# Slim Skeleton returns 404 Not Found

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

I've installed Slim4 via composer by following the installation guide command,

```
php composer.phar create-project slim/slim-skeleton slimexample
```

Then went to localhost:8080 which returned a json object as below.

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "error": {
    "type": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "description": "Not found."
  }
}
```

Any help on this on how to get started to run my first slim

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. There is no route for '/', see https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/4.0.1/app/routes.php

Only valid routes are

- /users
- /users/{id}

Therefore Slim returns 404 error code correctly.

(This omission has been addressed in [4.0.2](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/4.0.2/app/routes.php))

Comment: This is not correct. [Line 14 of the file]((https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/blob/master/app/routes.php#L14) defines a route callback for `/`, which shows "Hello world!" to the user.

Comment: Yes, because the route was added in commit https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton/commit/3ba4d97b5bee002385859357ab3107df99df37f3 few hours after I wrote my answer here...

Answer (score -1):

You were creating a slim project here with composer. after creation of the project are you starting with composer.

```
cd slimexample
php composer.phar start
```

Check [this](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton#slim-framework-4-skeleton-application) resource for more information